# Counting difference in days between two dates using lubridate

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I want to calculate difference between two dates using lubridate. I guess I am almost there but something is wrong in my try.

Here is the dataset I have,

```
library(lubridate)

day <- c(NA, NA, NA, "01", NA, "30", NA, "20", "09", NA)
my <- ifelse(is.na(day), NA, "042020")
value <- c(19, 23, 25, 26, 22, 12, 12, 34, 54, 23)
dmy <- ifelse(is.na(day), NA, paste(day, my, sep = ""))
endday <- ifelse(is.na(dmy), NA, rep("30042020"))
data <- data.frame(dmy, endday, value)
data$dmy <- lubridate::dmy(dmy)
data$endday <- lubridate::dmy(endday)
```

This will result the following data frame,

```
> data
          dmy     endday value
1        <NA>       <NA>    19
2        <NA>       <NA>    23
3        <NA>       <NA>    25
4  2020-04-01 2020-04-30    26
5        <NA>       <NA>    22
6  2020-04-30 2020-04-30    12
7        <NA>       <NA>    12
8  2020-04-20 2020-04-30    34
9  2020-04-09 2020-04-30    54
10       <NA>       <NA>    23
```

Now I want to calculate the difference between `dmy` and `endday` in days. That means, I should have something like a numeric vector,

```
> data$daydiff
<NA>
<NA>
<NA>
29
<NA>
0
<NA>
10
21
<NA>
```

I did this to achieve the result,

```
inter <- ifelse(is.na(data$dmy), NA, (data$endday %--% data$dmy))
inter
ddays(inter)
```

This gives me a result like this,

```
> ddays(inter)
 [1] NA                                 NA                                
 [3] NA                                 "-216483840000s (~-6859.96 years)"
 [5] NA                                 "0s"                              
 [7] NA                                 "-74649600000s (~-2365.5 years)"  
 [9] "-156764160000s (~-4967.56 years)" NA
```

How can I fix this to get my expected results?

Comment: `data$endday - data$dmy` as you're using lubridate, the most obvious answer is usually the case.

Comment: I am asking myself now, how is it possible that I have missed that obvious solution! Please post it as an answer. I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `lubridate` package eases most of the problems when working with dates. As stated in my comment this problem is easily solved by just subtracting the two dates, eg:

```
data$endday - data$dmy
```

gives the expected result.